# dialogo personalizado de un Spinner modo dialog

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, color

Hola me gustaria cambiar el color de fondo de mi sppiner en modo dialog, es decir cuando hago clic en el sppiner se me abre un dialog, en color balnco, lo que quiero es cambiar ese color blanco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi sppiner en el xml:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Sppiner"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/style_spinner"/>
```

Style_sppiner:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="@color/backgroundClaro" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        <stroke android:width="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el color de fondo de tu Spinner, puedes usar el atributo:

```
android:backgroundTint
```

ejemplo:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Sppiner"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:background="@drawable/style_spinner"/>
```

Pero en este caso como usas un `Drawable Shape` en tu Spinner, lo ideal es modificar el `Shape`, para cambiar el color de fondo, define el color especificandolo en :

```
<solid android:color="tu color" />
```

Ejemplo, cambiando el fondo de color verde:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:width="3dp"  />
</shape>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero no es eso lo que buscaba, con el `<solid android:color="tu color" />` solo consigo cambiar el fondo del spinner, lo quería es cambiar el fondo del dialogo que se abre al presionar en el spinner